# Generating encrypted fingerprint Key using fingerprint scanner in android

Tags: android

I am developing an app in which i need to scan fingerprint through inbuilt fingerprint scanner in an android device. From that fingerprint i need to generate an encrypted key that can be stored in the form of string in database. following is the code I tried:

```
    package com.ebookfrenzy.generatekey;

    import android.app.KeyguardManager;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.security.keystore.KeyProperties;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.hardware.fingerprint.FingerprintManager;
    import android.util.Base64;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import android.security.keystore.KeyGenParameterSpec;
    import android.security.keystore.KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException;

    import java.security.KeyStore;
    import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
    import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
    import java.security.NoSuchProviderException;
    import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
    import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
    import java.security.KeyStoreException;
    import java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException;

    import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
    import javax.crypto.Cipher;
    import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
    import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
    import javax.crypto.Cipher;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private static final String KEY_NAME = "example_key";
        private FingerprintManager fingerprintManager;
        private Cipher cipher;
        private FingerprintManager.CryptoObject cryptoObject;
        private KeyStore keyStore;
        private KeyGenerator keyGenerator;
        byte[] En_Key;
        private String encrypted;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            generateKey();
            if(cipherInit())
            {
                cryptoObject=new FingerprintManager.CryptoObject(cipher);
               encrypted=byteArraytoHex(En_Key);
                Toast.makeText(this,encrypted, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
        protected void generateKey() {
            try {
                keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(
                KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES,
                "AndroidKeyStore");
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException |
                    NoSuchProviderException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(
                        "Failed to get KeyGenerator instance", e);
            }
            try {
                keyStore.load(null);
        keyGenerator.init(new
                KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(KEY_NAME,
                KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT |
                        KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC)
                .setUserAuthenticationRequired(false)
                .setEncryptionPaddings(
                        KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7)
                .build());
        keyGenerator.generateKey();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException |
            InvalidAlgorithmParameterException
            | CertificateException | IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
public boolean cipherInit() {
    try {
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance(
                KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES + "/"
                        + KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC + "/"
                        + KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException |
            NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to get Cipher", e);
    }

    try {
        keyStore.load(null);
        SecretKey key = (SecretKey) keyStore.getKey(KEY_NAME,
                null);
        En_Key=key.getEncoded();
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        return true;
    } catch (KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException e) {
               return false;
            } catch (KeyStoreException | CertificateException
            | UnrecoverableKeyException | IOException
            | NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to init Cipher", e);
    }
}
public static String byteArraytoHex(byte[] array)
{
    StringBuffer hexStr=new StringBuffer();
    for(byte b:array) {
        int inval = b & 0xff;
        if (inval < 0x10) {
            hexStr.append("0");
        }
        hexStr.append(Integer.toHexString(inval));
    }
    return hexStr.toString();
    }
```

}

Comment: But this is not working. Where am I wrong? Can anybody Help?

Comment: "is not working" is not an exact problem description.

Comment: Well, Ok! In this code I dont understand where actually the key is getting generated. According to my understanding of android, SecretKey key is the key that is generated after fingerprint authentication. So I encoded it in Bytes form. Then I converted it into String using bytesArrayToHex function. But this is not actually working. Rest of the code is right. Can you help me understand where actually the encrypted key is getting generated? @Henry